# Нужна ли запятая в визитках?

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить запятую после номера телефона, перед эл. адресом, в частности, в визитке? Например:
Тел.: + 7 922 756 56,
E-mail: info@.......ru

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от дизайна визитки. Если у Вас телефоны и адреса перечислены в одну строку мелким шрифтом, тогда между ними должны быть какие-то разделители. Лучше, наверное, поставить запятые, но можно использовать специальные стандартные иконки (телефон и конверт, например) — тогда в запятых особой надобности нет. Если телефоны и адреса указаны в разных строчках, тогда ни в запятых, ни в других разделителях нет необходимости.

Сошлюсь также на [мнение Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=239608):

> **Вопрос № 239608**
>
> Нужно ли ставить запятую, точку или точку с запятой при перечислении контактной информации в несколько строк? Например:
>
> > Адрес: ул. Береговая, 25, кв. 7
> >     Тел.: 123-45-67, 765-43-21
> >     E-mail: mymail@mail.com
> >     Веб-сайт: mywebsite.com
>
> Особенно это касается визиток.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> В конце каждой строки точка или точка с запятой не требуется (особенно плохо смотрится точка на визитке после адреса электронной
>   почты).